# How do I change the color a dynamically made div on click with vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm in a online Boot-Camp, they've asked me to create a memory game and provided the following code. Step one is to change the color of a card on click. Vanilla JavaScript only.

I'm pretty sure that I need to select all div's, use a loop to attach an event listener, use the target attribute to toggle the class value so the user can see it. The problem is, I run into errors in the loop.

I just need a direction to run towards, a hint, and or helpful pointers. Not looking for someone to tell me the answer, just stumped.

```js
const gameContainer = document.getElementById('game');

const COLORS = [
  'red',
  'blue',
  'green',
  'orange',
  'purple',
  'red',
  'blue',
  'green',
  'orange',
  'purple',
  'indianred', // starting here down in the list, i added these colors.
  'darkslateblue',
  'limegreen',
  'coral',
  'rebeccapurple',
  'indianred',
  'darkslateblue',
  'limegreen',
  'coral',
  'rebeccapurple'
];

function shuffle(array) {
  let counter = array.length;

  while (counter > 0) {

    let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * counter);

    counter--;

    let temp = array[counter];
    array[counter] = array[index];
    array[index] = temp;
  }

  return array;
}

let shuffledColors = shuffle(COLORS); //array of colors

function createDivsForColors(colorArray) {
  for (let color of colorArray) {

    const newDiv = document.createElement('div');

    newDiv.classList.add(color);

    newDiv.addEventListener('click', handleCardClick);

    gameContainer.append(newDiv);
  }
}

// TODO: Implement this function!
function handleCardClick(e) {
  // you can use event.target to see which element was clicked
  // create a loop to loop through all the divs
  // access the classlist of the currently clicked div // this block of code is what've written
  const curDiv = e.target;
  const curDivColor = e.target.className;
  const divElement = document.querySelector('div');
  for (let flippedColor of divElement) {
    const index = shuffledColors.length;
    index--;
    curDiv.classList.toggle([i]);
    e.addEventListener;
  }
}

createDivsForColors(shuffledColors);
```

```css
#game div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 15%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 0.6rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Memory Game!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Memory Game!</h1>
    <div id="game">
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm pretty sure that I need to select all div's, use a loop to
>   attach an event listener, use the target attribute to toggle the class
>   value so the user can see it.

I don't think that's necessary. You can just change the class or style of the `div` that is clicked.

```js
const gameContainer = document.getElementById('game');

const COLORS = [
  'red',
  'blue',
  'green',
  'orange',
  'purple',
  'red',
  'blue',
  'green',
  'orange',
  'purple',
  'indianred', // starting here down in the list, i added these colors.
  'darkslateblue',
  'limegreen',
  'coral',
  'rebeccapurple',
  'indianred',
  'darkslateblue',
  'limegreen',
  'coral',
  'rebeccapurple'
];

function shuffle(array) {
  let counter = array.length;

  while (counter > 0) {

    let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * counter);

    counter--;

    let temp = array[counter];
    array[counter] = array[index];
    array[index] = temp;
  }

  return array;
}

let shuffledColors = shuffle(COLORS); //array of colors

function createDivsForColors(colorArray) {
  for (let color of colorArray) {

    const newDiv = document.createElement('div');

    newDiv.classList.add(color);

    newDiv.addEventListener('click', handleCardClick);

    gameContainer.append(newDiv);
  }
}

// TODO: Implement this function!
function handleCardClick(e) {
  // you can use event.target to see which element was clicked
  // create a loop to loop through all the divs
  // access the classlist of the currently clicked div // this block of code is what've written
  const curDiv = e.target;
  let shuffledColors = shuffle(COLORS);
  curDiv.style.background = shuffledColors[0]
}

createDivsForColors(shuffledColors);
```

```css
#game div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 15%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 0.6rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Memory Game!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Memory Game!</h1>
    <div id="game">
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
  
</html>
```